# Moving mainnav-icon under logo

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Currently im using a wp theme (http://preview.themezee.com/dynamicnews/), however I made a slight adjustment (http://www.angrycrows.com). As you can see in the original unedited theme the nav bar will turn in to a drop down based on the width of your browser. In my altered version (angrycrows.com) it does the same thing, but it doesn't position itself under the logo neatly (because of the change I made). My question is the following, how can I maintain my change with the larger nav bar being to the right side of the logo, while also having the mini-nav neatly positioned under the logo? Below is the altered CSS for angrycrows.

```
#navi-wrap {
background: #333;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 75px;
    right: 25px;
    float: right;
```

}

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have #navi-wrap rule for media="all"
If you want a responsive site you have to work with media queries.

Create a media query that manage the style for small screens. In your case your site change its style at 960px, so you have to create a media query for that width

```
@media (max-width: 960px){
   #navi-wrap {
     background: #333;
     margin: 0 10px;
   }
}

/* your full site style */
@media (min-width: 961px){
   #navi-wrap {
     background: #333;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 75px;
     right: 25px;
     float: right;
   }
}
```

Hope that helps.